# Unable to v-for an object array in an single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, nuxtjs

i need some help to work with v-for in NuxtJS.

I have an object that contain an list of tags objects like this:

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "example",
  "tags":[
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"a",
    "description":null
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "name":"b",
    "description":null
  }]
}
```

**INFORMATION**: These data are retreived via fetch() that made a call to an strapi API endpoint (Stored in episode)

Here is my loop to get into the tags:

```html
<span class="badge bg-red-500" :v-for="tag in episode.tags" :key="tag.id">
    {{tag.name}}
</span>
```

When i make that, i get an error message `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` or `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` (That depend if i use tag or tag.id as key)

I need understand why i'm getting that error (I understand the tag is null but why). Another thing, i can access to tags if i write for example `episode.tags[0].name`

I really need help to understand why this loop won't work. If someone cas make the light on this problem for me please, thanks in advance for all the helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching for more than 1 hour, and when i posted the question, found the problem in 1 minute ...

So if someone is facing same problem, just remove the `:` before `v-for` instruction as it's a native VueJS attribute. Not HTML